# How to get rid of the 'progress' cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an interval that launches an AJAX call to check if there is any update for the page (I imagine that it's similar to the mechanism used by Facebook or StackExchange to check for new notifications). The problem is that this call changes the cursor to the 'progress' or 'busy' cursor (visual problem) and disables to option to click on links (functional problem).

I suppose both problems are related. How can get rid of this effect or at least minimize the consequences?

Some code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    try {
        var mid = $($("ul#alert-messages li.regular")[0]).attr('ref');
        call_ajax('/load_alerts', {num:0, id:mid}, function (data) {
            if (data.ok) {
                for (var i=0; i<data.result.length; i++) {
                    // ....
                }
                // ...
            }
        }, function() {},          // Do not show any error for this!!
        false);                    // Do not change cursor!
    } catch (e) {}
}, 15000);

function call_ajax(url, data, fnSuccess, fnError) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': data,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success' : function(data) {
            if (fnSuccess) {
                fnSuccess(data);
            } else {
                if (typeof data.msg != 'undefined') {
                    topBar(data.msg, typeof data.ok != 'undefined' && data.ok? 'message' : 'error');
                }
            }
        },
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            if (fnError) {
                fnError(STR_ERROR_AJAX + textStatus);
            } else {
                topBar(STR_ERROR_AJAX + textStatus, 'error');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you please post some of your code?

Comment: Does it do that in all browsers? Can you reproduce the problem with a minimal example on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Xeon06: I'm experiencing it in FF and Chrome (Linux). Have not tested in other systems. Cannot give a js sample because I'll need a server side script to respond to the AJAX.

Comment: Fiddles can do Ajax calls to a mock API -- see the "Testing Ajax requests" drop-down on the left side.  If it's a client-side issue, it should be reproducible using any dummy data (or any sufficiently large dummy data, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I think that adding the option **async:true** to your ajax call will do. Otherwise the browser will freeze until ajax stops and that's not what you want

Comment: According http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ async is set by default, anyway I have tried to set it explicetly and the same result :(

Comment: Can you post some code please? Ajax shouldnt behave like that, which browser are you using?